# asp.net c# int variable increments by weird values on timer tick

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, timer

I have a timer that ticks every 1 second, and in that timer the variable `minuteCount` is set to increment by one like this:

```
minuteCount++;
```

However, the variable `minuteCount` increments on each tick by values ranging from 3 to 7. I view the value `minuteCount` in a label to see its value, and as I said it jumps from 1 to 7 and so on.

```
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static int minuteCount;
    //Also tried this: static int minuteCount = 0;
}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    minuteCount++;
}
```

Timer initialization in .aspx file (from comments):

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="1000" />
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us your timer initialization?

Comment: Its an asp.net timer so its initialized in the .aspx page: <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="1000" />

Comment: What triggers the update of the label? Are there any other instances of this class that might also be updating this `static` field?

Comment: The label is in a update panel that triggers when the timer ticks.

Comment: Don't make it a `static` variable, but track the minutes in a ViewState or Session.